# Sum of product with primes

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, cryptography

Let $b=e_1e_2,\ldots,e_n$ and $b'=e'_1e'_2,\ldots,e'_n$ be two distinct bit strings of equal length $n$ with same number of occurrences of zeros and ones. The bit string $b$ and $b'$ also must have $e_1 \neq e'_1$ and $e_n \neq e'_n$, that is, first and last bits must be distinct.

Examples of such pairs of bit strings:

**1**0**0** and **0**0**1**  --> bits in positions 1 and 3 mismatch, # of zeros is 2 and # of ones is 1

**0**10**1** and **1**10**0**  --> mismatch in positions 1 and 4, freq(0)=2 and freq(1)=2

**0101** and **1010**  --> all positions mismatch, freq(0)=2 and freq(1)=2

**0**1**0**0**1**0**1** and **1**1**1**0**0**0**0**  --> mismatch in positions 1, 3, 5 and 7, freq(0)=4 and freq(1)=3

Not that the number of positions with bit mismatches must be even.

Now let $p_0 p_1, q_0$ and $q_1$ be four distinct  primes. For any pair of bit strings define:

$$S_b=\sum_{i=1}^n \left( q_{e_i} \prod_{j=i+1}^n p_{e_j}\right) \mbox{   and    } \ S_b'=\sum_{i=1}^n \left( q_{e'_i} \prod_{j=i+1}^n p_{e'_j}\right)$$

Example: if $b$=**1**0**0** and $b'$=**0**0**1**  then $S_b=q_1 p_0 p_0 + q_0 p_0 + q_0$  and  $S_{b'}=q_0 p_0 p_1 + q_0 p_1 + q_1$.

Can $S_b=S_{b'}$ for $b\neq b'$ as above? If so, is there any condition that can be made on the primes $p_0, p_1, q_0$ and $q_1$ so that $S_b \neq S_{b'}$?

---

EDIT: let $p_0$ and $p_1$ be distinct primes, and let $q_0$ and $q_1$ be distinct positive integers. The product and type of bit strings are still the same as above.

Comment: EDIT: $q_0$ and $q_1$ don't need to be primes. Only $p_0$ and $p_1$ must be primes. But still need to impose other restriction(s) to avoid the equality  $S_b=S_{b'}$.

Comment: Any motivation for this?  Particularly the unusually specific constraints on $b,b'$ and why you are interested in the sum $S_b$?

Comment: The particular constrains on bit strings rise from an application to hash functions. The fact that $S_b=S_{b'}$ for those types of bit strings means that there is a collision for the hash.

Comment: Thanks.  It seems like you could ensure $S_b \ne S_{b'}$ by taking $p_0$ and $p_1$ close together (and increasing as some function of $n$) but $q_1$ much, much bigger than $q_0$.  Then whichever of $S_b$ or $S_{b'}$ has leading term $q_1 \prod p_*$ should dominate the other.  However, if this is going into a hash function then using this might demand an unreasonably large hash space.

Comment: Thanks. The sums above are not the hash and even though it grows very large it is still helpful for what I need. It seems that conditions such as $q_0 \gg q_1$  and $q_1 p_0>q_0 p_1$ are necessary conditions to impose. (or $q_1 \gg q_0$ with  $q_0 p_1>q_1 p_0$ using your suggestion).

Comment: Yeah I'd say it would be good to have $p_0$ and $p_1$ be small primes that are fairly close to adjacent so that the location of the $0$s and $1$ has little influence on the size.  But also maybe slowly increasing with $n$ so that the leading term can consistently dominate the $n$ (or so) other terms.  If this is helpful I can write this into an answer.

Comment: @ErickWong $p_0,p_1,q_0$ and $q_1$ are fixed numbers, they don't depend on the length $n$. Which relations such numbers should have such that inequality happens is what I'm interested in.

Comment: I see, that seems like a tall order as there is no size difference between $q_0$ and $q_1$ that can't be overcome by a very large value of $n$.  I suggest you edit the question to make it clear that you want the inequality to hold for _all_ $n$ and all admissible pairs of bit strings.  Even for a fixed $n$ that's a lot of inequalities to control.

Comment: @ErickWong please write your answer having $n$ slowly increasing as discussed above. So far your ideas have been the most helpful in solving this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to "can $S_b=S_{b'}$ for $b \neq b'$" is in the affirmative. This is checked fairly quickly by brute force. Let $b=100$ and $b'=001$ (as in your example). Then set $p_0=7$, $p_1=5$, $q_0=3$ and $q_1=2$. Now, \begin{equation}
S_b=q_1 p_0 p_0 + q_0 p_0 + q_0=2 \cdot 7 \cdot 7 + 3 \cdot 7+3=122 \\
S_{b'}=q_0 p_0 p_1 + q_0 p_1 + q_1=3 \cdot 7 \cdot 5+3 \cdot5 + 2 = 122
\end{equation}
In fact, for the given $b$ and $b'$ these primes are not unique in satisfying your criteria.  I do not have an answer to the second part of your question.

Edit: Consider the $4$-tuple $(p_0,p_1,q_0,q_1)$, then here is a large list of the $4$-tuples that satisfy $S_{100}=S_{001}$. As you can see, there are many possibilities. I hope this list can serve in answering the second part of your question.
$(7,5,3,2)$
$(19,13,3,2)$
$(23,5,11,2)$
$(31,13,5,2)$
$(41,17,5,2)$
$(43,29,3,2)$
$(42,13,7,2)$
$(47,5,23,2)$
$(59,5,29,2)$
$(61,41,3,2)$
$(67,13,11,2)$
$(61,41,3,2)$
$(79,53,3,2)$
$(83,5,41,2)$
$(5,7,2,3)$
$(11,7,5,3)$
et cetera